# jQuery code triggered twice for bind('keyup change') when pressing key

Tags: jquery, events

I have a number input that should trigger jQuery on every change.
To do this, I do a `$('#id').bind('keyup change', ...);`, which is triggered on any keyup or mouse-controller changed.

This works find for mouse clicks (triggers `change`) and for typing numbers (triggers `keyup`). But for the cursor keys it triggers both `change` and `keyup`. How can I make it so it only triggers once in all situations?

Here's an example showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/jSjkE/

Comment: if keyup counts as a change then just use change

Comment: `onchange` only fires when the element loses focus and has a different value than when it gained focus. Did you try HTML5's `oninput`? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jSjkE/2/)

Comment: @Hassek; You are right. The situation is a bit more complex due to the input being `type="number"`. I'll edit my question to explain.

Comment: Instead of `$('#id').bind('keyup change', ...);` use `$('#id').bind('input', ...);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have a wrong concept about the `onchange` event.

It does **NOT** fire when the element's value changes, instead, it fires only when 2 conditions are met:

- The element blurs (loses focus);
- The element has a different value than when it gained focus.

Note: The above is for inputs of type `text`. For types `checkbox`/`radio` it fires as soon as their `checked` property changes, and for `select` elements as soon as its selected option changes.

The `onchange` event (possibly wrongly) fires when you press Chrome's `input type="number"` up/down arrows. You should **not** rely on it, as many other major browsers don't even have an implementation of the number inputs yet and may not follow this behavior.

Instead, as you're using HTML5, you should rely on the `oninput` HTML5 event, which fires whenever the element's value is updated.

```
$(function() {
    var count = 0;
    $('#num').on('input', function(e) {
        console.log('update ' + (++count) + ' Value: ' + this.value);    
    });
});​
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jSjkE/17/)**

**edit:**

For older (and non-HTML5) browsers, you may use the `keyup` event as a fallback:

```
$('#num').on('input keyup', function(e) {
```

The most resilient way to do this for non-HTML5 browsers would be having a `setInterval` constantly checking if the element's value has changed, as `keyup` does not trigger if you select some text and drag it into the textbox - you could try `.on('input keyup mouseup'`, but then it wouldn't trigger if the user uses the browser's Edit > Paste menu.

**edit2:**

If you don't want to use `setInterval`, you can put a huge events map inside the `.on`/`.bind` and check if the value has changed by storing the current value in the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) of the element:

```
var count = 0;
$('#num').on('input keyup change', function(e) {
    if (this.value == $(this).data('curr_val'))
        return false;
    $(this).data('curr_val', this.value);

    console.log('update ' + (++count) + ' Value: ' + this.value);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jSjkE/20/)

I've added the `onchange` event to the events map, so even if the `oninput` and `onkeyup` fails (non-html5 browser using the browser's menu to paste data), the `onchange` event will still fire when the element loses focus.

Here's the final edit with a commented `setInterval` and [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to avoid using globals, so you can choose which of the fallbacks to use:

```
$(function() {
    var $num = $('#num');
    $num.data('curr_val', $num.val()); //sets initial value

    var count = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        if ($num.data('curr_val') == $num.val()) //if it still has same value
            return false; //returns false
        $num.data('curr_val', $num.val()); //if val is !=, updates it and
        //do your stuff
        console.log('update ' + (++count) + ' Value: ' + $num.val());
    }, 100); //100 = interval in miliseconds
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/jSjkE/25/)**

Comment: Browsers that do not support `type="number"` fall back to `type="text"`, which will still work fine. Checking only the `oninput` event will cause browsers that don't support it (IE8 and previous) to not trigger the code at all.

Comment: @Martijn I use [GCF](https://developers.google.com/chrome/chrome-frame/) on my pages for IE users, however yes, for non-HTML5 browsers you can add a `keyup` event there as well. The most resilient version of `oninput` for older versions is using a `setInterval` and checking if the value has changed, unfortunately.

Comment: Most users of old IE versions are corporate users that can't install GCF any more than they could install Chrome or a new IE version. I'll have a look at your setInterval suggestion, though it sounds like a very dirty solution.

Comment: @Martijn I do agree it's a dirty solution, edited my answer to include how I'd do it with a fiddle. I mentioned `setInterval`, as even though I dislike it, it's only 100% guaranteed way to simulate the `oninput` event. However, if you're happy with ~95%, my last edit should suffice. `:)`

Comment: Alright, with the `onchange` event, the function should run ~99% of the time, as it will at least fire when the element loses focus in a non-HTML5 browser after the user pasted through the menu.

Comment: I like your last solution. I don't see why it shouldn't work 100% of the time but my code can already deal with double triggers (it's a performance issue causing some relatively heavy calculations). I think the `input` event can be dropped as it should be covered by `change` and `keyup` and as an extra benefit, this solution should handle situations where the events are triggered but the value doesn't change (i.e. multiple pastes of the same number). Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the `change` warrants that it'll be fired at least when the element loses focus. `=]` I've added the `setInterval` fiddle as well, if you ever need to switch fallbacks. Both of my fallbacks store the current value in the `.data()` of the element and checks against it, which prevents the function from firing repeatedly if the value hasn't changed, as you commented. No problem. `=)`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').unbind('keyup').bind('keyup',function(e){ ...
```

Comment: I don't know who downvoted my answer, but it's 100% correct and straight to the point.

Comment: Not sure either why it has downvotes - worked for me (+1). Thank you!!!

Comment: Thank's mike, appriciate it. Lot's of people here claim to be pros and downvote for no reason without havin' a clou.

Comment: Incomplete Code only answers are subject to down votes. Better is to add a bit of explanation of what this does and why/how it works (for example, why is the unbind needed) and how it applies to the problem described in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Keyup always works for input, search fields, and you can prevent change event as below: and keep change event working for other controls i.e. select.

```
// Prevent trigger change as keyup event already triggered so no twice call
if ((e.target.type == 'input' || e.target.type == 'search') && e.type == 'change') {
    return;
}
```